# Query that works with MariaDB but fails with a syntax error on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This query works on MariaDB, but not MySQL. I get a error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'integer) HOUR`

This is a really dense query. So, even though I've looked through the manual I've had trouble identify which function is actually causing the issue.

```
SELECT  1 AS one
FROM sched_walks INNER JOIN walks ON walks.id = sched_walks.walk_id
WHERE sched_walks.d_acc = 1
  AND sched_walks.docent_id = 6
  AND (sched_walks.id != 714)
  AND (
    scheduled_for_utc <= '2018-03-17 14:34:31.000000'
      AND
    DATE_ADD(
      scheduled_for_utc,
      INTERVAL CONVERT(REPLACE(COALESCE(sched_duration, walks.duration), ' hours', ''), integer) HOUR
    ) >= '2018-03-17 12:34:31.000000'
  )
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cast()` instead:

```
  INTERVAL CAST(REPLACE(COALESCE(sched_duration, walks.duration), ' hours', '') as signed) HOUR
```

Actually, you can use `convert()` . . . the key is using `signed` or `unsigned`.

Or just use silent conversion:

```
  INTERVAL COALESCE(sched_duration, walks.duration) + 0 HOUR
```

Comment: This fails on MariaDB. Is there anything that works for both?

Comment: Both of these should work in both databases.  The `integer` is optional but `signed` and `unsigned` should work.  (Note:  I just fixed a typo in the second answer.)